What do the status bar indicators of Byobu mean?
Byobu's status bar shows these indicators by default:

Can anyone explain exactly what each of them means?

Which indicators exactly are you confused by? Most are self explanatory

Doesn't https://www.byobu.org/documentation tell you what you want to know?

@Ramhound I'm confused by "37!", "2.28" and the couple with the percentages

Percentages are your disk utilization.

I’m voting to close this question because it fails to demonstrate a minimum necessary self-effort, such as reading the documentation available online for the tool.

They are called the 'status notifications', and can take up to two lines.
They can be widely configured using the configuration utility.
In your screenshot, from left to right, according to documentation, they are.

37! = 37 updates available.


updates_available  - the number of updates available on the system; displayed in the lower bar toward the right in white text on a red background with a trailing '!'  sign;  if  anyupdates  are  marked  'security  updates',  then  there  will  be  a total of two trailing exclamation points, '!!'


2d0h = system uptime since last boot


uptime - the total system uptime since last boot; displayed in the lower  bar  toward  the right in blue text on a grey background


2.28 = system load average, last minute


load_average - the system load average over the last 1 minute; displayed in the lower  bar toward the right in black text on a yellow background

Note that in Linux, 'system load average' is the average number of tasks currently executed by the CPU and of tasks waiting in the queue (reference)

8x = CPU count


cpu_count - the number of cpu's or cores on the system; displayed in the lower bar  toward the right in the default text color on the default background, followed by a trailing 'x'


4.1GHz = current CPU frequency


cpu_freq  - the current frequency of the cpu in GHz; displayed in the lower bar toward the right in white text on a light blue background


31.2G98% = Total RAM and percentage used


memory - total memory available and used percentage in the system; displayed in the  lower bar toward the right in white text on a green background


224G93% = Disk space available and percentage used


disk  -  total  disk space available and total used on / directory; displayed in the lower bar on the far right in white text on a light  purple  background;  override  the  default directory  by  specifying  an  alternate  mount  point  with  MONITORED_DISK=/wherever  in $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/statusrc


Current date


date  - the system date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or you can set this to any valid strftime(3) you like in $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/datetime; displayed in the lower on the  far  right  in  the default text color on the default background


Current time


time - the system time in HH:MM:SS format (by default), or you can set this to  any  valid strftime(3)  you like in $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/datetime; displayed in the lower bar on the far right in the default text and default background colors

